# using C - string has \n\r (ascii) in the string and i want to convert it to actual newline CR

Tags: c, string, embedded

i am presented with a string that looks like this:

"Mary had a little lamb \n\r its fleece was white as snow"

the \n\r is the actual ascii characters for these (0x5C6E5c72)

is there an "easy" way to take the string and convert the \n\r to 0x0D0A?

i was thinking to tokenize on the 0x5C6E5c72 into an array and then format the new string with the NLCR in between..

anybody know if there is a useful c library or anything to do this easier?

Comment: \r = CR (Carriage Return) // Used as a new line character in Unix. 

\n = LF (Line Feed) // Used as a new line character in Mac OS. 

\r\n = CR + LF // Used as a new line character in Windows. Now, what do you want??

Comment: i have a string as above, it has the ascii characters  \ n \ and r right in the string, i want to convert them into \n\r..  basically 0x5c6e5c72 into 0x0d0a

Comment: Rephrased: how do I convert "\\n\\r" to "\n\r"? Right?

Comment: @Adam - you are assuming that this is in the program source.  "I am presented with" makes it sound more like this is data provided by something else at runtime, and that the escape sequences need to be identified and interpreted.  But we'll have to see what Daniel says.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, If his input were the two characters 'back-slash' and 'n', then the C representation of that would be "\\n".

Comment: Sorry, the software i am changing  is receiving data that users type in and the user instructions were "if you want a new line in your string, use \n\r to make the new line".  i think i could change this to prompt for \\n\\r if necessary, maybe that makes things easier...  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @DanielScire No, the user should enter \n\r. You can use my code below to interpret the escape codes.

Comment: Note that `0D0A` is CR LF, not LF CR. The `\n\r` would be backwards even if it weren't escaped. (There is no ASCII newline character; there is such a construction in Unicode but that seems like a joke in this context.)

Answer (score 1):

gcc (GCC) 4.7.3: gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 echo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Destructively interpret escape codes in a string.
void interp_backslash(char* str) {
  char* r = str;
  char* w = str;

  while (*r) {
    *w = *r;
    if ('\\' == *r) {
      ++r;
      switch (*r) {
      case 'r': *w = '\r'; break;
      case 'n': *w = '\n'; break;
      case '\\': *w = '\\'; break;
      // add other cases here
      default:
        printf("error\n");
        exit(-1);
      }
    }
    ++r;
    ++w;
  }
  *w = '\0';
}

// Similar to echo -e
// For example: ./echo "mary\n\rlamb"
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
    interp_backslash(argv[i]);
    printf("%s", argv[i]);
    if (i != argc -1) { printf(" "); }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Modified from previous version. Hopefully a little clearer now.

Comment: No, it would need to translate `\r` to newline and `\n` to carriage return, but the exercise here isn't mapping escape sequences.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a textual search and replace.

Note that the standard ASCII newline sequence `0D0A`, used by e.g. MSDOS descendants, is CR LF not LF CR, and it would be represented by `\r\n`, never by `\n\r`.

Following the general pattern I've used for search and replace in C…

```
void fix_newlines( char * base ) {
    char * read = base;
    char * write = base;
    while ( char * next = strstr( read, "\\n\\r" ) ) {
        memmove( write, read, next - read ); /* Copy text. */
        write += next - read; /* Advance past text. */
        read = next + 4; /* Advance past text and escape sequences. */
        strcpy( write, "\r\n" ); /* Translate to CRLF. */
        write += 2; /* Advance past CRLF. */
    }
    strcpy( write, read ); /* Copy trailing text. */
}
```